# Error when scheduling refresh for Python script in Power BI published workspace

Tags: python, powerbi, connection, cloud, workspace

I do the get data -> py script command on powerbi. Copy paste the code and able to visualise data.
But after publishing to a workspace i see it doesn't refresh on the workspace unless i refresh on my system's powerBI Desktop.

Hence even scheduled refresh isn't available.

How do it correct this. Should I upload the code somewhere on cloud.

Answer (score 0):

When using Python scripts in Power Query, it is necessary to establish a personal gateway on your computer for running the Python scripts. Power BI Service cannot run Python itself.

Very lame, I know, but this is a very immediate limitation of using Python in your Power Query ETL.

Comment: I tried installing the gateway in standard Mode and it gives errors.